# Node.js is not accessible using external IP (Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I have created a node.js server, which listens to:

```
 server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

I tried to create a docker container and run it on my ubuntu(20) server using this tutorial:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

The docker container is up:

```
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED    
> STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES 32b2e34bf21f  
> my-server   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up
> About an hour   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   distracted_blackburn
```

and is accessible within the server (checked using curl -i localhost:3000 and curl -i 0.0.0.0:3000)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 May 2021 04:19:44 GMT
ETag: W/"b0-17959a6f300"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 176
Date: Thu, 13 May 2021 03:39:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

<html>

<head>
  <title>Express</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Express</h1>
  <p>Welcome to Express</p>
</body>

</html>
```

More information:
netstat -tulpn has this row related to the port.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I added ufw rules so it doesn't seem to be FW problem.

```
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But no matter what I'm doing, I can't access the server from **server-ip:3000** in my browser(outside the ubuntu)

Thank you.

Comment: what is the status code?

Comment: Not getting error code but ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: in your situation, may I know which service provider you are using?

Comment: @ShayVikel You may want to check if the website responds internally from the server, by trying: `curl http://localhost:3000/` and `curl http://server-ip:3000/`. Troubleshooting can be scoped down this way.

Comment: if you use VPS/VDS server you can check existing ip interface in command `ip a`
in some cases your service provider should pass specific port  to your VM
or you can try use 80 port:
`0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp` - 80 port sometimes is open by default

Comment: @kmmanoj both curls show that the service works.